# Is 'Almost everyone' both a guarding term and assuring term here?

Tags: argumentation, language

Source: [Lecture 2-5](https://class.coursera.org/thinkagain-005/lecture/254) ([transcription](https://class.coursera.org/thinkagain-005/lecture/subtitles?q=254_en&format=txt)), *... How to Reason and Argue*, by Prof W Sinnott-Armstrong.
The following is from a question that pops up during the video at the 5  min 28 seconds juncture.

> [Question:] If someone says, “Almost everyone agrees with me,” is the particular term “almost” being used as a guarding term or as an assuring term in this context?
>
> [Choice 1:] Guarding term
>
> > Well done! "**Almost** everyone agrees” is harder to refute than the unqualified
> >      “Everyone agrees”, so the term “**almost**” is added in order to make the claim harder to refute. The claim cannot be refuted, for example, simply by pointing out one person who disagrees. *Notice that the whole phrase “**Almost** everyone agrees with me” is used for assuring, but the single word “**almost**” can still be used for guarding within the larger assuring phrase.*
>
> [Choice 2:] Assuring term     [Choice 3:] Neither

Why is the answer definitively 1? **almost**'s function is ambiguous;
it can assure (if the skeptic believes: 'almost everyone' means a sufficiently higher number),
or it can guard (if the skeptic believes: 'almost everyone' means 'far fewer than 'everyone') .

Also, does the italicised part of the prof's answer contradict his choice of 1 as the answer?

Comment: This seems to be a language problem rather than a philosophical one. "Almost" in philosophical lingo means 'at least one' or possibly > .5 (out of 1). There's little ambiguity in the quote you're supplying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the prof means to distinguish between the **term** "almost" and the **expression** "almost everyone".
The expression "almost everyone" is primarily assuring (enlarging).
But the term "almost", within the expression "almost everyone", is guarding (diminishing).
So, the prof's italicized words do not seem to me to contradict his choice of #1 as the answer.